# How to disable windows auto driver install

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers, mouse

I plugged in my **BarMouse Slim** ergonomic roller mouse (I have been unable to find a live manufacturer site but believe they were produced for a Swedish company) into a machine with **Windows 8.1 Pro 32-bit on Intel x64** It seemed to work briefly and then stopped.  It still works as expected in **Ubuntu Linux**.  I think it stopped working when I connected to the Internet.

I now see **USB composite device** and a **First Touch RF Programmer** listed under USB controllers in Device Manager.  There is also 5 HID devices showing up and my regular mouse and KBD are still working as normal in Win 8 and in parallel with the roller mouse in Linux.

The unit has a Cypress chip inside it and it is reporting a **USB\VID_04B4&PID_F115** which corresponds to a Cypress controller with USB support.

I think Windows went and loaded some proximity card writer drivers and my roller mouse has disappeared.  What is the normal way to sort something like this out?

Are there any workarounds I can use?

I disabled and uninstalled the RF Card driver but no change.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned below in the comments uninstalling the RF card writer USB device did not help. Running the driver search app did not find any missing or out of date drivers.

Today I plugged the roller mouse into a Win 8 laptop and it works fine.  No drivers were loaded.  It looks like it is a Win 8.1 problem.  Any ideas on how to tell windows not to load drivers for this specific USB class?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: See if this helps you find the right driver. http://www.driveridentifier.com/. Be careful with what drivers you download. This site helps you get the matching driver but it can be for a different OS

Comment: Wow, one serious bit of data mining software. It found no missing drivers for me.  The roller mouse is supposed to work without any drivers as a standard HIR USB mouse, it just looks like the same PID has been reused.